# Woocommerce Order admin / edit page - how to trigger totals recalculation via JS upon order change?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Is there a way to trigger this recalculation upon change? 
It can be done manually by clicking the button at the bottom of the order items rows, but can a change in the order be detected on the client side?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's always the .trigger() function:

```
$('button.calculate-action').trigger('click');
```

Unfortunately, this button pops a confirmation dialog that, to my knowledge, can't be forced to click 'Yes' or skipped in some way.  The function called by clicking the `Recalculate` button is `meta-boxes-order-items.recalculate()`, which is tucked away in the `meta-boxes-order.js` file within a private variable.  If possible we could just call that function directly, but alas, this isn't possible ( unless someone else knows... )

Perhaps clicking the Save button will help accomplish your goal?

`$('button.save-action').trigger('click');`